# Discord.JS-Commando Purge.JS Not Firing

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, commando

Yo, so I'm trying to readd my purge command to a discord bot I'm building and it keeps claiming the number is invalid.

Basically it's throwing the first error in the code response.

Does anyone know what I messed up in my code? I would more than grateful for any help with this.

Here is my `purge.js` code:

````js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { Command } = require('discord.js-commando');

module.exports = class PurgeCommand extends Command {
    constructor(client) {
        super(client, {
            name: 'purge',
            aliases: ['p', 'c', 'clean'],
            group: 'admin',
            memberName: 'purge',
            description: 'Purge some messages from a Text Channel.',
            examples: ['purge 5'],
            guildOnly: true,
            throttling: {
                usages: 1,
                duration: 3
            },
            clientPermissions: ['MANAGE_CHANNELS'],
            userPermissions: ['MANAGE_CHANNELS'],

            args: [
                {
                    key: 'amount',
                    label: 'number',
                    prompt: 'Please input a number between 0 and 100.',
                    type: 'integer'
                }
            ]
        });
    }

    run(message, args) {
        const amount = parseInt(args[0]) + 1;

        if (isNaN(amount)) {
            return message.reply('```css\n[ERROR] Please provide a valid number.\n```');
        } else if (amount <= 0 || amount > 100) {
            return message.reply('```css\n[ERROR] You need to input a number between 0 and 100.\n```');
        }

        message.channel.bulkDelete(amount, true).then(deletedMessages => {
                var botMessages = deletedMessages.filter(m => m.author.bot);
                var userPins = deletedMessages.filter(m => m.pinned);
                var userMessages = deletedMessages.filter(m => !m.author.bot);

                const embed = new Discord.MessagEmbed()
                    .setTitle("Purge Command Issued")
                    .setDescription('The following messages have been purged.')
                    .setColor('RANDOM')
                    .setFooter('TwitchBot | twitchbot.newhorizon.dev', 'https://images-ext-2.discordapp.net/external/6vZM6YeZGzfxd4PF_aw3UnNHZafkdNlRoLp46YJ7hkU/%3Fsize%3D256/https/cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/779442792324661249/26206ede07f20447bf380df44b429db7.png')
                    .setThumbnail('https://images-ext-2.discordapp.net/external/6vZM6YeZGzfxd4PF_aw3UnNHZafkdNlRoLp46YJ7hkU/%3Fsize%3D256/https/cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/779442792324661249/26206ede07f20447bf380df44b429db7.png')
                    .setTimestamp()
                    .setURL("https://twitchbot.newhorizon.dev")
                    .addField("Bot Messages Purged", botMessages.size, false)
                    .addField("User Pins Purged", userPins.size, false)
                    .addField("User Messages Purged", userMessages.size, false)
                    .addField("Total Messages Purged", deletedMessages.size, false);

                message.channel.send(embed);
            })
            .then(console.log(args[0]))
            .catch(err => {
                console.error(err);
                message.channel.send('There was an error with the command! Please contact a developer via our Discord!');
            });
    }
};
````

I'm running `node`:`12.0.0` and `discord.js`:`12.5.1` if it helps.

--EDIT--

Removing the following code from the top:

````js
        if (isNaN(amount)) {
            return message.reply('```css\n[ERROR] Please provide a valid number.\n```');
        } else if (amount <= 0 || amount > 100) {
            return message.reply('```css\n[ERROR] You need to input a number between 0 and 100.\n```');
        }
````

displays the following error in console:

```js
 TypeError [MESSAGE_BULK_DELETE_TYPE]: The messages must be an Array, Collection, or number.
     at TextChannel.bulkDelete (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/interfaces/TextBasedChannel.js:361:11)
     at PurgeCommand.run (/app/commands/admin/purge.js:33:25)
     at CommandoMessage.run (/app/node_modules/discord.js-commando/src/extensions/message.js:222:34)
     at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
     at async CommandDispatcher.handleMessage (/app/node_modules/discord.js-commando/src/dispatcher.js:143:19) {
   [Symbol(code)]: 'MESSAGE_BULK_DELETE_TYPE'
```

---EDIT---

added `.then(console.log(args[0]))` and got this:

```js
 debug: Running command admin:purge.
 undefined
TypeError [MESSAGE_BULK_DELETE_TYPE]: The messages must be an Array, Collection, or number.
     at TextChannel.bulkDelete (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/interfaces/TextBasedChannel.js:361:11)
     at PurgeCommand.run (/app/commands/admin/purge.js:33:25)
     at CommandoMessage.run (/app/node_modules/discord.js-commando/src/extensions/message.js:222:34)
     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
     at async CommandDispatcher.handleMessage (/app/node_modules/discord.js-commando/src/dispatcher.js:143:19) {
   [Symbol(code)]: 'MESSAGE_BULK_DELETE_TYPE'

}
```

--- EDIT 03/14/2021 1 ---

Ok so still trying get this working, this is what I currently have.

````js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { Command } = require('discord.js-commando');

module.exports = class PurgeCommand extends Command {
    constructor(client) {
        super(client, {
            name: 'purge',
            aliases: ['p', 'c', 'clean'],
            group: 'mod',
            memberName: 'purge',
            description: 'Purge some messages from a Text Channel.',
            examples: ['purge 5'],
            guildOnly: true,
            throttling: {
                usages: 1,
                duration: 3
            },
            clientPermissions: ['MANAGE_MESSAGES'],
            userPermissions: ['MANAGE_MESSAGES'],

            args: [{
                key: 'purgeamnt',
                label: 'Number',
                prompt: 'Please input a number between 0 and 100.',
                type: 'integer'
            }]
        });
    }

    run(msg, args) {
        let ch = msg.channel;

        var purgeamnt = args[0];
        var purgelimit = Number(purgeamnt) + 1;
        msg.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: purgelimit }).then(messages => {
            msg.channel.bulkDelete(messages).then(deletedMessages => {
                    var botMessages = deletedMessages.filter(m => m.author.bot);
                    var userPins = deletedMessages.filter(m => m.pinned);
                    var userMessages = deletedMessages.filter(m => !m.author.bot);

                    if (purgeamnt <= 0) {
                        return msg.reply('Please input a number between 0 and 100.');
                    } else if (channel => channel.type === 'text') {

                        const embed = new Discord.MessagEmbed()
                            .setAuthor('Twitchbot', 'https://images-ext-2.discordapp.net/external/6vZM6YeZGzfxd4PF_aw3UnNHZafkdNlRoLp46YJ7hkU/%3Fsize%3D256/https/cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/779442792324661249/26206ede07f20447bf380df44b429db7.png')
                            .setTitle("Purge Command Issued")
                            .setDescription('The following messages have been purged.')
                            .setColor('RANDOM')
                            .setFooter('Twitchbot | twitchbot.newhorizon.dev', 'https://images-ext-2.discordapp.net/external/6vZM6YeZGzfxd4PF_aw3UnNHZafkdNlRoLp46YJ7hkU/%3Fsize%3D256/https/cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/779442792324661249/26206ede07f20447bf380df44b429db7.png')
                            .setThumbnail('https://images-ext-2.discordapp.net/external/6vZM6YeZGzfxd4PF_aw3UnNHZafkdNlRoLp46YJ7hkU/%3Fsize%3D256/https/cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/779442792324661249/26206ede07f20447bf380df44b429db7.png')
                            .setTimestamp(new Date().toISOString())
                            .addField("Bot Messages Purged", botMessages.size, false)
                            .addField("User Pins Purged", userPins.size, false)
                            .addField("User Messages Purged", userMessages.size, false)
                            .addField("Total Messages Purged", deletedMessages.size, false);
                        ch.send(embed);
                    }
                })
                .then(console.log(args[0]))
                .catch(err => {
                    console.error(err);
                    ch.send('```css\n[ERROR] ' + err.code + ': [' + err.message + ']\n```');
                })
        });
    }
};
````

ok and here is the console error it is throwing:

```js
2021-03-14T19:21:22.109551+00:00 app[worker.1]: Unhandled rejection: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
2021-03-14T19:21:22.109553+00:00 app[worker.1]: limit: Value "NaN" is not int.
2021-03-14T19:21:22.114093+00:00 app[worker.1]: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
2021-03-14T19:21:22.114094+00:00 app[worker.1]: limit: Value "NaN" is not int.
2021-03-14T19:21:22.114095+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at RequestHandler.execute (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:154:13)
2021-03-14T19:21:22.114095+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
2021-03-14T19:21:22.114096+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at async RequestHandler.push (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:39:14)
2021-03-14T19:21:22.114096+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at async MessageManager._fetchMany (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/managers/MessageManager.js:140:18) {
2021-03-14T19:21:22.114097+00:00 app[worker.1]:   method: 'get',
2021-03-14T19:21:22.114097+00:00 app[worker.1]:   path: '/channels/812939122519703572/messages?limit=NaN',
2021-03-14T19:21:22.114098+00:00 app[worker.1]:   code: 50035,
2021-03-14T19:21:22.114098+00:00 app[worker.1]:   httpStatus: 400
2021-03-14T19:21:22.114099+00:00 app[worker.1]: }
```

--- EDIT 03/14/2021 2 ---

````js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { Command } = require('discord.js-commando');

module.exports = class PurgeCommand extends Command {
    constructor(client) {
        super(client, {
            name: 'purge',
            aliases: ['p', 'c', 'clean'],
            group: 'mod',
            memberName: 'purge',
            description: 'Purge some messages from a Text Channel.',
            examples: ['purge 5'],
            guildOnly: true,
            throttling: {
                usages: 1,
                duration: 3
            },
            clientPermissions: ['MANAGE_MESSAGES'],
            userPermissions: ['MANAGE_MESSAGES'],

            args: [{
                key: 'amount',
                label: 'Number',
                prompt: 'Please input a number between 0 and 100.',
                type: 'integer'
            }]
        });
    }

    run(msg, args) {
        let ch = msg.channel;


        const amount = Number(args.amount)
        if (Number.isNaN(amount)) {
            return msg.reply('```css\n[ERROR] Please provide a valid number.\n```')
        }

        if (amount <= 0 || amount > 100) {
            return msg.reply(
                '```css\n[ERROR] You need to input a number between 0 and 100.\n```'
            )
        }

        const limit = amount + 1
        const messages = msg.channel.messages.fetch({ limit })
        const deletedMessages = msg.channel.bulkDelete(messages).then(deletedMessages => {
                var botMessages = deletedMessages.filter(m => m.author.bot);
                var userPins = deletedMessages.filter(m => m.pinned);
                var userMessages = deletedMessages.filter(m => !m.author.bot);

                const embed = new Discord.MessagEmbed()
                embed.setAuthor('Twitchbot', 'https://images-ext-2.discordapp.net/external/6vZM6YeZGzfxd4PF_aw3UnNHZafkdNlRoLp46YJ7hkU/%3Fsize%3D256/https/cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/779442792324661249/26206ede07f20447bf380df44b429db7.png')
                embed.setTitle("Purge Command Issued")
                embed.setDescription('The following messages have been purged.')
                embed.setColor('RANDOM')
                embed.setFooter('Twitchbot | twitchbot.newhorizon.dev', 'https://images-ext-2.discordapp.net/external/6vZM6YeZGzfxd4PF_aw3UnNHZafkdNlRoLp46YJ7hkU/%3Fsize%3D256/https/cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/779442792324661249/26206ede07f20447bf380df44b429db7.png')
                embed.setThumbnail('https://images-ext-2.discordapp.net/external/6vZM6YeZGzfxd4PF_aw3UnNHZafkdNlRoLp46YJ7hkU/%3Fsize%3D256/https/cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/779442792324661249/26206ede07f20447bf380df44b429db7.png')
                embed.setTimestamp(new Date().toISOString())
                embed.addField("Bot Messages Purged", botMessages.size, false)
                embed.addField("User Pins Purged", userPins.size, false)
                embed.addField("User Messages Purged", userMessages.size, false)
                embed.addField("Total Messages Purged", deletedMessages.size, false);
                ch.send(embed = embed);

            })
            .then(console.log(args[0]))
            .catch(err => {
                console.error(err);
                msg.reply('```css\n[ERROR] ' + err.code + ': [' + err.message + ']\n```');
            })
    }
};
````

--- EDIT 03/14/2021 3 ---

````js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { Command } = require('discord.js-commando');

module.exports = class PurgeCommand extends Command {
    constructor(client) {
        super(client, {
            name: 'purge',
            aliases: ['p', 'c', 'clean'],
            group: 'mod',
            memberName: 'purge',
            description: 'Purge some messages from a Text Channel.',
            examples: ['purge 5'],
            guildOnly: true,
            throttling: {
                usages: 1,
                duration: 3
            },
            clientPermissions: ['MANAGE_MESSAGES'],
            userPermissions: ['MANAGE_MESSAGES'],

            args: [{
                key: 'amount',
                label: 'Number',
                prompt: 'Please input a number between 0 and 100.',
                type: 'integer'
            }]
        });
    }

    async run(msg, args) {
        let channel = msg.channel;


        const amount = Number(args.amount)
        if (Number.isNaN(amount)) {
            return msg.reply('```css\n[ERROR] Please provide a valid number.\n```')
        }

        if (amount <= 0 || amount > 100) {
            return msg.reply(
                '```css\n[ERROR] You need to input a number between 0 and 100.\n```'
            )
        }

        const limit = amount + 1
        const messages = await msg.channel.messages.fetch({ limit })
        const deletedMessages = await msg.channel.bulkDelete(messages).then(deletedMessages => {

                var botMessages = deletedMessages.filter(m => m.author.bot);
                var userPins = deletedMessages.filter(m => m.pinned);
                var userMessages = deletedMessages.filter(m => !m.author.bot);

                let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();

                embed.setAuthor('Twitchbot', 'https://images-ext-2.discordapp.net/external/6vZM6YeZGzfxd4PF_aw3UnNHZafkdNlRoLp46YJ7hkU/%3Fsize%3D256/https/cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/779442792324661249/26206ede07f20447bf380df44b429db7.png')
                embed.setTitle("Purge Command Issued")
                embed.setDescription('The following messages have been purged.')
                embed.setColor('RANDOM')
                embed.setFooter('Twitchbot | twitchbot.newhorizon.dev', 'https://images-ext-2.discordapp.net/external/6vZM6YeZGzfxd4PF_aw3UnNHZafkdNlRoLp46YJ7hkU/%3Fsize%3D256/https/cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/779442792324661249/26206ede07f20447bf380df44b429db7.png')
                embed.setThumbnail('https://images-ext-2.discordapp.net/external/6vZM6YeZGzfxd4PF_aw3UnNHZafkdNlRoLp46YJ7hkU/%3Fsize%3D256/https/cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/779442792324661249/26206ede07f20447bf380df44b429db7.png')
                embed.setTimestamp(new Date().toISOString())
                embed.addField("Bot Messages Purged", botMessages.size, false)
                embed.addField("User Pins Purged", userPins.size, false)
                embed.addField("User Messages Purged", userMessages.size, false)
                embed.addField("Total Messages Purged", deletedMessages.size, false);
                channel.send(embed = embed);

            })
            .then(console.log())
            .catch(err => {
                console.error(err);
                channel.send('```css\n[ERROR] ' + err.code + ': [' + err.message + ']\n```');
            })
    }
};
````

Comment: Is it throwing an error or just run `message.reply('```css\n[ERROR] Please provide a valid number.\n```');`? Have you checked the value of `args[0]`?

Comment: I can check the error log but it's running the `message.reply('```css\n[ERROR] Please provide a valid number.\n```');` fpr sure

Comment: ok so sorry for the late reply, there doesnt appear to be a error log of any kind so it seems it's just running the `message.reply('```css\n[ERROR] Please provide a valid number.\n```');`

Comment: Updated my post with the console error

Comment: You should still check what the value of `args[0]` is. If you remove `isNaN(amount)`, you receive `TypeError [MESSAGE_BULK_DELETE_TYPE]` because `amount` is not a number. That's why you should check what `console.log(args[0])` is.

Comment: I updated my post with the log from your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`args` is an object. So, you should be using `args.amount` (the key is `amount`) or use object destructuring to get the amount argument.

````js
async run(message, args) {
  const { channel } = message
  const amount = Number(args.amount)
  if (Number.isNaN(amount)) {
    return message.reply(
      '```css\n[ERROR] Please provide a valid number.\n```'
    )
  }

  if (amount <= 0 || amount > 100) {
    return message.reply(
      '```css\n[ERROR] You need to input a number between 0 and 100.\n```'
    )
  }

  const limit = amount + 1
  try {
    const messages = await channel.messages.fetch({ limit })
    const deletedMessages = await channel.bulkDelete(messages)
    const botMessages = deletedMessages.filter(m => m.author.bot)
    const userPins = deletedMessages.filter(m => m.pinned)
    const userMessages = deletedMessages.filter(m => !m.author.bot)
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    // ...
    channel.send(embed)
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
    channel.send(
      '```css\n[ERROR] ' + err.code + ': [' + err.message + ']\n```'
    )
  }
}
````

For more information, check the [docs](https://discordjs.guide/commando/args.html#using-arguments-in-commands) on using command arguments.

Comment: This is responding with `[ERROR] MESSAGE_BULK_DELETE_TYPE: [The messages must be an Array, Collection, or number.]`. It also made me remove the awaits.

Comment: @JoshuaLewis Can you update the question with your latest code?

Comment: @JoshuaLewis [`channel.messages.fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch) returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). You have to chain `then` on it or use `await` if it is an `async` function. As you can see in my answer, the `run` function is `async` and I'm `awaiting` the result of `channel.messages.fetch`.

Comment: hmmm. it made me remove the awaits when i tried to run it... will try again though.

... wait i see why it made me delete them. i think i might have that fixed now lol

Comment: @JoshuaLewis What do you mean by "it made me remove the awaits"? What happens when you try the code in my answer?

Comment: I think i figured it out. I forgot to add async to the run part before lol

Comment: Yip this fixed it. tyvm =)

Comment: sorta. it's giving this when it tries to send the embed: `[ERROR] undefined: [Assignment to constant variable.]`

Comment: @JoshuaLewis You can't reassign values to a `const` variable. Your embed sending code should be `ch.send(embed)`. No need to assign values.

Comment: hmmm now its throwing `[ERROR] undefined: [Cannot read property 'author' of undefined]`

Comment: @JoshuaLewis Can you update the question with your latest version of the code?

Comment: @JoshuaLewis You're mixing `then` and `await`. Since you're using `async/await`, you don't need to use `then`. See my updated answer. I would strongly recommend you read up on [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await).